# Make a golfing language

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

In this challenge, you get to create a language. Although you have to provide code in other languages, you will only be rated based on the language. Here are the requirements.

1. You must invent a programming language that is Turing complete.
2. You will choose a real (as in existed before this question did) language. It must be a different paradigm then the made up language.
3. You will write a boot strapping compiler. This means you write a program in your new language, that will take code in your new language, and translate it to code in your real language.
4. So people can run it initially, you will provide an interpreter (or compiler) in a real language (which may or may not be written the real language you choose above) to run programs in the new language. This does not need to be golfed.

Note: Your language can't have builtin functions for generating code in the real language. This basically means that if the real language were proprietary, your language wouldn't violate its copyright by making it to easy to generate its code.

Scoring:

Your score is the size of your compiler. Your will find your programs' sizes using `roundup(s*log_2(a))` where s is the number of characters in your program and a is the number of available characters in your language (meaning huge penalties if you use Chinese characters or something.)

Tip: String characters count too, so if you are looking to really shrink how many characters are available, you will need to find a way to represent strings with few characters.

Smallest score wins!

So in summary, you invent a turing-complete language X. Then you implement an interpreter or compiler for it in Y. Finally, you implement a compiler for X in X itself. (Based on a comment from Victor.)

Comment: So I must to write a code in language A that translates code in language B to language C. Isn't writing an interpreter in language A to interpret language B acceptable?

Comment: No no no. You write code in A to translate code in A to B and C. Code in A that interprets A would be pointless. You just write code in D (which may or may not be B or C) to interpret A so you can run it the first time.

Comment: We have to write TWO??

Comment: Well, I didn't want a pig latin of one of the languages. Should I make it one you think?

Comment: Well, this will take a considerably large amount of time...

Comment: Okay, I will make it one. But then it has to be a different paradigm than it.

Comment: Translating brainfuck to haskell doesn't seem too hard,  one can think of something abusing the state monad. Translating brainfuck to python is a piece of cake

Comment: Except you would have to do it in brainf***.

Comment: And it should be a new language you come up with.

Comment: What if the language isn't character based, like Piet?

Comment: So this is basically 1. Invent a turing-complete language X. 2. Implement an interpreter or compiler for it in Y. 3. Implement a compiler for X in X itself. Got it right?

Comment: According to the rules, taking C and swapping `{` and `}` would be a valid entry? You may have a tough time coming up with a definitive line for how different the languages have to be.

Comment: @KendallFrey Rule 2 would stop you from doing that. But probably there is some way to circunvent that anyway.

Comment: @Victor Well, most languages don't have a defined paradigm. Some languages are functional, procedural, imperative, object-oriented, etc.

Comment: It is sort of a guideline. I don't think there is a way to make it definite. Is there a tag for that?

Comment: I feel like the spec for this is too ambiguous.

Comment: @Victor, that's not how I understand it. I think your step 2 corresponds to the question's step 4, but for your step 3 to correspond to the question's step 3 the question would need to relax from writing a source-source translator to writing a compiler.

Comment: Aw man, why is this closed? It's one of the only genuinely interesting challenges I've seen on this site.

Comment: Plus it really isn't that hard. It sort of seems like it's been closed on the basis that it sounds a bit too much like hard work, which is kind of a bad sign for a site that's meant to be about puzzles and challenges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Brainfuckoff -> Javascript, 527 characters, 3463 points

My language, Brainfuckoff is a brainfuck-derived language with the following changes:

- It has a new instruction `*` which sends everything in input to the output, until the end-of-input is reached.
- It has a new instruction `^` which sends everything following this and before the following backtick to the output.
- It takes a line of the input at a single shot in the start of the program, consuming each char with the `,` instruction.

So, here is a partially-golfed javascript compiler for my language:

```javascript
function bfg(j){
  w=String.fromCharCode;
  r='(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);';
  for(x=0;x<j.length;x++){
    q=j.charCodeAt(x);
    if(q==91)r+='while(~~m[p]){';
    if(q==93)r+='}';
    if(q==62)r+='p++;';
    if(q==60)r+='p--;';
    if(q==43)r+='m[p]=1+~~m[p];';
    if(q==45)r+='m[p]=-1+~~m[p];';
    if(q==46)r+='t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);';
    if(q==44)r+='if(c<n.length)m[p]=n.charAt(c++);';
    if(q==94){z=j.indexOf(w(96),x+1);r+='t+='+w(34)+j.substring(x+1,z)+w(34)+';';x=z}
    if(q==42)r+='t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;'
  }
  return r+'return t})'
}
```

Here is a brainfuck Hello World program:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

Compiling it:

```javascript
program = '++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.';
jsprogram = bfg(program);
alert(jsprogram);
```

The output:

```javascript
 (function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];while(~~m[p]){p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];while(~~m[p]){p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];p--;p--;p--;p--;m[p]=-1+~~m[p];}p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];p++;m[p]=-1+~~m[p];p++;p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];while(~~m[p]){p--;}p--;m[p]=-1+~~m[p];}p++;p++;t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p++;m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p++;p++;t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p--;m[p]=-1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p--;t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];m[p]=-1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p++;p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);p++;m[p]=1+~~m[p];m[p]=1+~~m[p];t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);return t})
```

Running that:

```javascript
program = '++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.';
input = '';
jsprogram = bfg(program);
alert(eval(jsprogram)(input));
```

The output:

```
Hello World!
```

This other brainfuckoff's Hello World is simpler:

```javascript
program = '^Hello World!`'
input = '';
jsprogram = bfg(program);
alert(eval(jsprogram)(input));
```

The output:

```
Hello World!
```

Great, now a compiler of brainfuckoff to javascript written in brainfuckoff (527 characters):

```
^(function(j){w=String.fromCharCode;r='(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);';for(x=0;x<j.length;x++){q=j.charCodeAt(x);if(q==91)r+='while(~~m[p]){';if(q==93)r+='}';if(q==62)r+='p++;';if(q==60)r+='p--;';if(q==43)r+='m[p]=1+~~m[p];';if(q==45)r+='m[p]=-1+~~m[p];';if(q==46)r+='t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);'; if(q==44)r+='if(c<n.length)m[p]=n.charAt(c++);';if(q==94){z=j.indexOf(w(96),x+1);r+='t+='+w(34)+j.substring(x+1,z)+w(34)+';';x=z}if(q==42)r+='t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;'}return eval(r+'return t})')})('`*^')`
```

Compiling the compiler:

```javascript
program = "^(function(j){w=String.fromCharCode;r='(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);';for(x=0;x<j.length;x++){q=j.charCodeAt(x);if(q==91)r+='while(~~m[p]){';if(q==93)r+='}';if(q==62)r+='p++;';if(q==60)r+='p--;';if(q==43)r+='m[p]=1+~~m[p];';if(q==45)r+='m[p]=-1+~~m[p];';if(q==46)r+='t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);'; if(q==44)r+='if(c<n.length)m[p]=n.charAt(c++);';if(q==94){z=j.indexOf(w(96),x+1);r+='t+='+w(34)+j.substring(x+1,z)+w(34)+';';x=z}if(q==42)r+='t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;'}return eval(r+'return t})')})('`*^')`";
jsprogram = bfg(program);
alert(jsprogram);
```

The compiled compiler:

```javascript
(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);t+="(function(j){w=String.fromCharCode;r='(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);';for(x=0;x<j.length;x++){q=j.charCodeAt(x);if(q==91)r+='while(~~m[p]){';if(q==93)r+='}';if(q==62)r+='p++;';if(q==60)r+='p--;';if(q==43)r+='m[p]=1+~~m[p];';if(q==45)r+='m[p]=-1+~~m[p];';if(q==46)r+='t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);'; if(q==44)r+='if(c<n.length)m[p]=n.charAt(c++);';if(q==94){z=j.indexOf(w(96),x+1);r+='t+='+w(34)+j.substring(x+1,z)+w(34)+';';x=z}if(q==42)r+='t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;'}return eval(r+'return t})')})('";t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;t+="')";return t})
```

Running the compiled compiler to compile the first Hello World:

```javascript
program1 = "^(function(j){w=String.fromCharCode;r='(function(n){m=[];p=0;c=0;t=n.substring(0,0);';for(x=0;x<j.length;x++){q=j.charCodeAt(x);if(q==91)r+='while(~~m[p]){';if(q==93)r+='}';if(q==62)r+='p++;';if(q==60)r+='p--;';if(q==43)r+='m[p]=1+~~m[p];';if(q==45)r+='m[p]=-1+~~m[p];';if(q==46)r+='t+=String.fromCharCode(~~m[p]);'; if(q==44)r+='if(c<n.length)m[p]=n.charAt(c++);';if(q==94){z=j.indexOf(w(96),x+1);r+='t+='+w(34)+j.substring(x+1,z)+w(34)+';';x=z}if(q==42)r+='t+=n.substring(c);c=n.length;'}return eval(r+'return t})')})('`*^')`";
jsprogram1 = bfg(program1);
input1 = '++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.'
jsprogram2 = eval(jsprogram1)(input1);
input2 = '';
alert(eval(jsprogram2)(input2));
```

The output:

```
Hello World!
```

Calculating the score:

```
roundup(527 * log_2(asciiCharOf('~') - asciiCharOf(' ') + 1))
roundup(527 * log_2(126 - 32 + 1))
roundup(527 * log_2(95))
roundup(527 * 6.5698556083309478416638388523962)
roundup(3462.3139055904095125568430752128)
3463
```

Note: There are indeed some ways to reduce the size of the interpreter in maybe ~20%. But this was already hard enough to do for me.

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I intended. You rounded up incorrectly though.

Comment: @PyRulez Fixed. Sorry for the mistake, I was a bit nervous at the time.

Comment: @PyRulez Since it is unlikely that this question will get any more attention, and since my answer is the only answer that is complete, detailed, not abusing the scoring, and meeting your expectations, could you please accept it?

Comment: Nice name (just get rid of brain from it)

Answer (score 5):

### Score = (Number too long for an SE post * log_2(1)) = 0

Given how the score is weighted by the number of characters available in the language, the less the better:

**1.)** My language (X) is called Compressed Unary.  It is similar to [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) in that it only has one available character in the language. Unlike Unary, it uses the number "1" instead of "0".  It improves on Unary by assigning the operators in a different bit order, with lower values assigned to operations that occur more often.  It is proven to be Turing complete in that it can be trivially converted to Brainfuck.

The code is a string of 1s, and the length of the code determines the logic (see the description of Unary from the link above for more details. The encoding is as follows:

```
Brainfuck   Binary
+           (1000)
-           (1001)
>           (1010)
<           (1011)
.           (1100)
,           (1101)
[           (1110)
]           (1111)
```

All the binary is combined from left to right and the resulting number is how many "1"s should be in the source code.  This should yield much smaller code that Unary, but will absolutely suck as a golfing language.  Much better for code bowling (see the compiler below and you'll see why).

**2.)** I chose C#. It was easy, I could port an existing BF implementation ([props to the original author](http://sharpecoding.com/projects/random-fun/brainfuck-interpreter/)), and given that log_2(1) is zero, the length of the code doesn't have any effect my score.

**3.)** The source code is too long to include here (stupid 30k character limit), in fact the number is too long to post here (it is 123411 characters in hex notation).  The following [link](http://pastebin.com/1KSdmSGB) will give you the number in hex. You can create the bootstrap compiler simply by typing that many ones in a text file.
Like I said, this completely sucks as a golfing language. It's much worse than C# for golfing.

**4.)** Once you type out the source code (I'd include a download link, but it would take *way too long* even on a fast fiber connection), you can run it through the following interpreter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;

namespace CompressedUnary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger code = new BigInteger(0);
            int next = 0;

            try
            {
                using (FileStream source = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    next = source.ReadByte();
                    while (next != -1)
                    {
                        if (next != 49)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Syntax error.");
                            break;
                        }
                        code += 1;
                        next = source.ReadByte();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException oops)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oops.Message);
            }

            if (next == -1)
            {
                string processed = PreProcess(code);
                Interpreter runner = new Interpreter(Console.OpenStandardInput(), Console.OpenStandardOutput());
                runner.Run(processed);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        static string PreProcess(BigInteger input)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
            BigInteger current;

            while (input > 0)
            {
                BigInteger.DivRem(input, 16, out current);
                switch ((int)current)
                {
                    case 0:    
                        output.Append("+");
                        break;
                    case 1:    
                        output.Append("-");
                        break;
                    case 2:    
                        output.Append(">");
                        break;
                    case 3:    
                        output.Append("<");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        output.Append(".");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        output.Append(",");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        output.Append("[");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        output.Append("]");
                        break;
                }
            }
            return output.ToString();
        }

        enum ILCode : byte
        {
            NextCell = (byte)'>',
            LastCell = (byte)'<',
            Increment = (byte)'+',
            Decrement = (byte)'-',
            Output = (byte)'.',
            Input = (byte)',',
            BeginLoop = (byte)'[',
            EndLoop = (byte)']'
        }

        class Machine
        {
            public int pointer = 0;
            private int cell = 0;
            private readonly byte[] cells;
            private readonly Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

            public Machine(int memory)
            {
                cells = new byte[memory];
            }

            public byte CurrentCell
            {
                get { return cells[cell]; }
                set { cells[cell] = value; }
            }

            public void Increment()
            {
                if (CurrentCell == 255)
                    CurrentCell = 0;
                else
                    CurrentCell++;
                pointer++;
            }

            public void Decrement()
            {
                if (CurrentCell == 0)
                    CurrentCell = 255;
                else
                    CurrentCell--;
                pointer++;
            }

            public void NextCell()
            {
                cell++;
                pointer++;
            }

            public void LastCell()
            {
                cell--;
                pointer++;
            }

            public void BeginLoop()
            {
                stack.Push(pointer);
                pointer++;
            }

            public void EndLoop()
            {
                if (CurrentCell == 0)
                    pointer++;
                else
                    pointer = stack.Pop();
            }
        }

        class Interpreter
        {
            private readonly Stream output;
            private readonly StreamReader reader;
            private readonly Dictionary<byte, Action> actions;
            private readonly Machine machine;

            public Interpreter(Stream ioin, Stream ioout, int memorySize = 30000)
            {
                output = ioout;
                reader = new StreamReader(ioin);
                machine = new Machine(memorySize);
                actions = new Dictionary<byte, Action>
                    {
                        {(byte) ILCode.BeginLoop, machine.BeginLoop},
                        {(byte) ILCode.EndLoop, machine.EndLoop},
                        {(byte) ILCode.Increment, machine.Increment},
                        {(byte) ILCode.Decrement, machine.Decrement},
                        {(byte) ILCode.NextCell, machine.NextCell},
                        {(byte) ILCode.LastCell, machine.LastCell},
                        {(byte) ILCode.Input, InputCurrentByte},
                        {(byte) ILCode.Output, OutputCurrentByte},
                    };
            }

            public void Run(string program)
            {
                byte[] instructions = program.Select(c => (byte)c).Where(b => actions.ContainsKey(b)).ToArray();
                while (machine.pointer < instructions.Length)
                {
                    Action action = actions[instructions[machine.pointer]];
                    action.Invoke();
                }
                byte[] newLine = Environment.NewLine.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
                output.Write(newLine, 0, newLine.Length);
            }

            private void InputCurrentByte()
            {
                byte next = (byte)reader.Read();
                machine.CurrentCell = next;
                machine.pointer++;
            }

            private void OutputCurrentByte()
            {
                output.WriteByte(machine.CurrentCell);
                machine.pointer++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FORE!**

Comment: Nice exploit. I should have added log_2 of the length, but too late now.